# Getting a " A nested call to gcloud failed" error when trying to create a datalab in gcloud

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Just starting to use Google Cloud Platform. Trying to familiarize myself with tensorflow and am following the Stack Skills tutorial Machine Learning and TensorFlow on the Google Cloud. I am using the gcloud console on firefox and following the tutorial I use the commands

- gcloud config set core/project my-first-project
- gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-f
- datalab create --no-create-repository    tensorflow

but I keep getting this error and haven't been able to find a solution that fixes it on the web.

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - Failed to find project my-first-project
>
> A nested call to gcloud failed.

Any ideas or solutions whats going on or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that "my-first-project" does not exist as a project that your account has access to.    You need to create the project first either through the console, or via the command line:

```
gcloud projects create my-first-project
```